# java.lang.NullPointerException: null at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log(SSLLogger.java:182)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, spring-boot-admin

We are using Spring boot admin and getting this error on logging request.
If anyone encountered this issue and resolved your comment will be highly appreciable

```
[https-jsse-nio-8000-exec-5] o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint[175] - Error running socket processor java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log(SSLLogger.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.warning(SSLLogger.java:162)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyShareExtension$CHKeyShareConsumer.consume(KeyShareExtension.java:373)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension.consumeOnLoad(SSLExtension.java:542)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.consumeOnLoad(SSLExtensions.java:185)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1154)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:849)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:810)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1052)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:999)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:443)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:507)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Line 182 of [SSLLogger.java](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLLogger.java) reads: `if (logger.isLoggable(level)) {`.  Apparently your `logger` variable is null.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Robert.
How can we make sure that Logger is not Null

Comment: Line 64 reads: `String p = GetPropertyAction.privilegedGetProperty("javax.net.debug"); if (p != null) {`.

Comment: And then: `} else { logger = null; }`.  So it would seem that `privilegedGetProperty("javax.net.debug")` must return an actual property in order for the logger to not be null.

Comment: what does it mean GetPropertyAction.privilegedGetProperty("javax.net.debug").
and where javax.net.debug needs to be configured